# jQuery to remove part of class name

Tags: jquery, class, replace

I have a list item generated via wordpress. Each list item has a class for example cat-item-14.

I need to manipulate this class only to show the number so to remove 'cat-item-' and just leave the class as '14'

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: alternatively, you can add a filter to the wordpress function outputting the classes.

Comment: Cronco has probably got a good point here... better to do this task somewhere not so client side - don't know anything about wordpress though so can't help there.

Comment: Agreed with Cronco although my jQuery is better than my php - I'm currently outputting my taxonomy using the wordpress post_class() function I've added the term_id to the output of post_class() in the functions file as below - at present but its outputting just the id - ideally it would need to be cat-item-id to match up with my category list and filter the items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather extract the number and then append it to the attribute, instead of erasing all the other classes, because it could interfere with wordpress plugins that actually use the original classes:

```
$("ul > li").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
        n = $el.attr("class").match(/cat-item-(.*)/)[1];

    $el.addClass(n);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
var value

$("ul > li").each(function() {
    value = $(this).attr("class").replace("cat-item-", "");
    $(this).attr("class", value);
});
```

Be aware though that it's not good practice to have a class starting with a numeric character.

Comment: Thanks - that's similar to what I had been trying but wasn't quiet there, done the trick thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What has Tom suggested you to do will does the trick.

But.. 
Numbers are not allowed to be first letter of class or ID name... So... I would add underscore character to the class name...

```
$("ul > li").each( function() {
   var value = $(this).attr("class");
   value.replace("cat-item-", "_");
   $(this).attr("class", value);
});
```

Comment: beat me to it with the class name bit.

Comment: Thanks I take on board your comment re-class names in this case is only used to manipulate using js so hopefully will do what I need.